# What are the primary stats of your followers?

Tags: diablo-iii

What are the primary stats of each of your followers? The Enchantress is obviously int, but the other ones I'm not sure about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The primary attack stats of the followers can easily be tested by swapping in specific stat boosting equipment, but you don't need to do that as the game clearly tells you when you mouse over their stats in their equipment menu that they are as follows:

- **Templar: Strength.**
- **Scoundrel: Dexterity.**
- **Enchantress: Intelligence.**

Comment: Also, if you mouse over their stats in their equipment menu, it will say "The X's primary stat."

Comment: @Fluttershy I did not know that. I intuitively knew because it was as obvious as a giant rampaging neon elephant by considering how tightly typed the followers are. I will add this to the answer.

Comment: I thought it was pretty obvious, just by their archtype ... however I came here looking just in case as I started to receive items for specific followers that hand counter-intuitive stats (i.e.: Templar-only item that had only Int on it). Thanks for the info, though.